# Checking database table for inserted, updated, or delete rows through a c# console application?

Tags: c#, sql-server

**Here is the situation:** 
The c# application that I have developed uses store procedures to update xml results in another web application. The process that I use is through XML Diff and Patch tools through Microsoft.

**Here is example code:**

```
        public void MainTask(string[] proc, string[] otpt)
        {
            try
            {
                sw = File.AppendText(loggingFolder + loggingFile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                e.CreateDirectoriesError(ex.Message, errorFolder + errorFile);
            }
            sw.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MainStart"]);
            sw.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Main1"]);
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < proc.Length; i++)
                {

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(proc[i], setupConnection(conn));
                    sw.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Main2"] + proc[i]);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    rdr = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
                    sw.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Main3"] + proc[i] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Main4"]);
                    rdr.Read();
                    xml.Load(rdr);
                    if (xml.InnerXml == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["_blankString"])
                    {
                        rdr.Close();
                        closeConnection();
                        continue;
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Main5"] + proc[i] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Main6"] + otpt[i]);
                    xml.Save(sourceFolder + otpt[i]);
                    sw.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Main7"] + otpt[i] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Main8"] + sourceFolder + otpt[i]);
                    rdr.Close();
                    closeConnection();


                    sw.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Main9"]);
                    XmlWriterSettings setWriter = new XmlWriterSettings();
                    setWriter.Indent = true;
                    writ = XmlWriter.Create(differenceFolder + otpt[i], setWriter);
                    PatchDifference(GenerateDiffernce(sourceFolder + otpt[i], destinationFolder + otpt[i], writ, otpt[i]), destinationFolder + otpt[i]);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MainError"] + ex.Message);
                e.MainError(ex.Message, errorFolder + errorFile);
            }
            sw.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MainDone"]);
            sw.Close();
        }
```

**My problem:**
I need to check the table that I am calling in my cmd to check whether or not any tables have been updated in the last 24 hours. If() the tables have not been updated or new ones inserted continue to the next table. Else run the rest of the procedure.

I have checked out many possibilities to try to accomplish this by using either Hash or check-sum values. However I'm concerned about the reality of reliability with these methods of implementation. Another way I could approach this situation is looking at dates, however some of the tables have UpdatedDate columns and others don't. So I am looking for something universal.

Comment: one way is to add after insert / after update triggers to each table, and keep a record in a different table for last update/insert time in each table

Comment: Or add the necessary audit column(s) to the table itself.

Comment: [How to track data changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx)

Comment: @sstan Thanks for the information! I might be able to lean on this documentation. I am looking for something that doesn't implement triggers and extra tables just to track simple changes and etc. Thanks for the link!